# How the ring of algebraic numbers looks like?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

> Suppose I have an algebraic number field $K = \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha \in O_K$, ring of algebraic integers. Is there a criterion that tells us when $O_K =\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ by any chance?

For example, if $\alpha^3 - \alpha - 1 = 0$, then $O_K =\mathbb Z[\alpha]$. I was wondering if there is an easy way to see this.

Thanks!

Comment: If you are actually able to locate an integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$, you can then try and check to see if the discriminant of the power basis coincides with the discriminant of $\mathcal{O}_K$. If they do, you know the power basis is actually an integral basis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Such a basis for the ring of integers is called a *power basis*, and the corresponding field is said to be *monogenic*. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monogenic_field.

Besides the cases mentioned in the wikipedia article, this is generally not an easy question to answer. See this MO question: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21267/which-number-fields-are-monogenic-and-related-questions